# Loop through two Lists

Tags: loops

```
lst = [2,4,6]
lst2 = [4,8,9]
new_lst = []
```

how do i go through every element in lst and multiply them by lst2[0], then go thought every element in lst and multiply them by lst2[1] and finally go through every element in lst and multiply them by lst2[2].

I will add all the answers new_lst

new_lst = [2*4, 4*4, 6*4, 2*8, 4*8, 6*8, 2*9, 4*9, 6*9]

Comment: Are you writing in LOOP or what language do you use?

Comment: I am using Python.

Answer (score 2):

This may work,

```
lst = [2,4,6]
lst2 = [4,8,9]
new_lst = []

for i in lst2:
    # i will equal 4, then 8, then 9
    for j in lst:
        # j will equal 2, then 4, then 6
        new_lst.append(i*j)

print(new_lst)   
> [8, 16, 24, 16, 32, 48, 18, 36, 54]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not based in Python, but in C# but because you didn't get any answer yet, I answer so you can try to rebuild:

In C# you would do:

List list = new List();

```
for(int i = 0; i < lst.length; i++)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < lst2.length; j++)
   {
      list.Add(lst[i] * lst2[j]);
   }
}
```